# Tomcat sets JAVA_HOME to point at JRE rather than JDK

Tags: java, tomcat, java-home, java-melody

I'm using JavaMelody on Tomcat 7 in order to monitor memory usage. When I fire up Tomcat and navigate to the /monitoring page, all is fine and dandy. However, when I try and generate a Memory Histogram, a pop-up appears informing me that 'Memory histogram is not supported because the server uses the JRE and not the JDK.
This is confirmed in the start up section of the logs:

INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre

However, my JAVA_HOME variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\
Why does Tomcat append 'jre' to the JAVA_HOME, and how do I stop it from doing it?

Thanks

Angus

Comment: How do you start your tomcat?  Is there any kind of script, windows service definition, etc.?  Maybe we would need more information on that

Comment: I use the startup.bat script.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the catalina.bat start script of tomcat 7:

```
rem   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
rem                   Required to run the with the "debug" argument.
rem
rem   JRE_HOME        Must point at your Java Runtime installation.
rem                   Defaults to JAVA_HOME if empty. If JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME
rem                   are both set, JRE_HOME is used.
```

Please check if you have set a JRE_HOME variable, because that would explain your problem